# How should I prefix my variables with the same name?

Tags: c#, winforms, naming-conventions

I'm creating a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) based application in C#. My form's constructor takes parameter `string title`, and it then saves that value to `string this.Title` attribute, and finally I create a windows label `Label this.Title`.

The problem is obvious: My `Label` and `string` have the same name, and I'm curious about naming conventions in C#. What should I do?

Here's the full code:

```
// BNForm.cs
public partial class BNForm : Form
{
    public string Title;

    public BNForm(string title)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        InitControls();
    }
}

// BNForm.Designer.cs
partial class BNForm
{
    private Label Title;

    private InitControls()
    {
        this.Title = new Label();
        this.Title.Text = this.Title; // Trying to access the string here
        this.Title.AutoSize = true;
        this.Title.Location = new Point(15, 15);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Title); // Trying to access the Label here
    }
}
```

I first called my label variable `label_Title`, but later I have to add a new variable: `Button[] Buttons` which should then be called `buttonArray_Buttons`, which sounds stupid to me.

What should I name my variables? Is there even a rule for this kind of naming?

Comment: usually they prefix the labels with "lbl" so, it would become "lblTitle". However, I must mention that winforms is a dinosaur technology and if I were you, I'd be spending my time learning the current stuff, which is all XAML-based.

Comment: We have a very simple naming convention in our company. Parameters to methods get an a in front of them, and members get an m in front of them. like mTextureManager.Load(aFileName) ... But this question is only matter of personal preferences, so we can't give you a good answer.

Comment: You should take a look at [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx) where Microsoft advises not to use prefix notations.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks for the tip, I'll make sure to take a look at XAML-based stuff :-) @dowhilefor The problem is: I got two members with same name, one of them being `string` and the other one is `Label`.

Comment: `Label` is a private field, and should, as a side-note, therefore be camelCased: `label`.

Comment: @Antonijn You mean it should be `private Label title` ?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Common wisdom says that you should not expose fields to the outside world. If you need to expose something to the outside world, use a property, not a field.

Comment: I advise to name private members with m_Label or _Label, in that case it will be easy to find private members

Comment: @Epsil0neR If you stick to keeping fields private and lowerCamelCase and expose to the outside via CapitalCamelCase named properties, you don't need to prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now that I know much more of `C#` (and "Antonijn" mentioned it already in the comments) I am aware that `private` member variables should begin with small letter and `public` properties start with a capital letter.

This in mind, my `public string Title;` stays as it is, but the label turns into `private Label title;` which lets me separate these two from each other. Thanks everyone for the answers, even when none of them helped me with this exact problem (good suggestions, I just don't like `lblTitle` etc.), they gave me much more knowledge of C#.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use prefixes because they're considered bad practice. Just use common sense. How about calling your label field `titleLabel` instead? "Does what it says on the tin"... i.e. it's unambiguous.

Comment: Um. Are suffixes better practice than prefixes?

Comment: Yes, because they're a far more natural construct.

Comment: Not a lot then. Hungarian isn't usually objected to because it's unnatural, but because the type has been exposed with the name, suffix or prefix or even labTitleel :) doesn't really address that.

Answer (score 1):

Well first I'd stay well clear of variable names that only differ by case, generally that's a huge comprehensibility issue.
I tend to prefix my arguments in a method with arg, some people don't like that though.

LblTitle or some equivalent hungarian notation is a fairly standard approach. I try to avoid that though. What if you want to diplay the title in say a textbox for instance, rename everything or enable confusion mode.

In this case I'd rename the Title Property to DisplayTitle or the the label to TitleDisplay.

The other option is to create a struct or class to hold the title Property then you can do

[this.]Title.Text = [this.]Setup.Title;

Whatever you do pick one standard and stick to it, is about the only rule.

Comment: I gave it an upvote, not accepting an answer doesn't mean I dont like it. It's just not what **I** need.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Aye was two though some flyby downvoted it. I'd just like to know why, there's always a possibility it's deserved and so no comment is learning opportunity missed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several dos and donts in variable naming as well as other prefix guidelines for different controls.

DOs

- Do name all identifiers with meaningful names describing their
  function.
- Do prefix member fields with “m_” but nothing else (f
  prefix, suffixes, etc.)
- Do name all identifiers with English names.
- Do use Pascal casing for namespace, type, enum, method names.
- Do use camel casing for parameters, fields and local variables.
- Do prefix all interfaces with I. Do suffix all exception classes with
  Exception.
- Do suffix all attribute classes with Attribute. Do suffix    all
  event handlers with EventHandler.
- Do use upper casing for constants.

DON'Ts

- Do not use Hungarian notation.
- Do not use upper casing for any identifiers longer than two characters (except constants as stated above).
- Do not distinguish between identifiers just by their case.
- Do not use abbreviations or contractions.
- Do not use acronyms that are not generally accepted in the industry.
- Do not use upper casing for acronyms that are longer than two characters.
- Do not use identifier names that duplicate keywords or commonly used .NET namespaces.
- Do not prefix enum, class, struct or delegate names.
- Do not suffix enum types with Enum.

Variable naming suggestions. Just prefix all variables depending on the object type:

- Button -     btn
- CheckBox -   chk
- ComboBox -   cmb
- DataColumn    - dcol
- DataGrid -   dgrid
- DataGridDateTimePickerColumn -   dgdtpc
- DataGridTableStyle        - dgts
- DataGridTextBoxColumn -  dgtbc
- Dialog    - dlg
- GroupBox  - gbx
- ImageList     - iml
- Label     - lbl
- ListBox   - lbx
- ListView -   lv
- Mainmenu -   mm
- MenuItem -   mi
- MDI-Frame -  frm
- MDI-Sheet -  sht
- NumericUpDown -  nud
- Panel     - pnl
- PictureBox -     pbx
- RadioButton -    rbt
- SDI-Form - form
- StatusBar     - stb
- TabControl -     tabs
- TabPage   - tab
- TextBox   - txt
- ToolBar   - tbr
- ToolBarButton     - tbb
- Timer     - tmr
- UserControl   - usr
- WindowsPrincipal  - wpl
- GridEX    - gex
- TreeView  - tv
- UICommand     - cmd
- EditBox   - edt
- DataView  - viw
- DataTable     - tbl
- DataSet   - ds

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does your advice "Do not use abbreviations or contractions" tie in with the lower part of your post? You're contradicting yourself.

Comment: Guys, yeah there might be some contradictions here but there are probably not too many and having any rules will be probably more helpful than not having any.

Comment: "How does your advice "Do not use abbreviations or contractions" tie in with the lower part of your post? You're contradicting yourself" - abbreviations are meant not for prefixes but for the actual variable names. Let's not take everything too literally ;)

Comment: Re Hungarian notation: yes - this does conflict with the rule of prefixing controls but if applied only to variables you use in your methods or properties/members of your classes than it completely makes sense.

Comment: lblTTiltle is a variable, it was just set in the designer and the autocoded, instead of typed by thee and me.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson agree completely with you. It's just that I meant variables that are not created automatically by designer but those we as devs create ourselves manually. 

I agree that this above looks weird when you look at it but it works just fine when you actually start using it.

Comment: I don't know about the DOs and DON'Ts, but I do see that the prefix list is really helpful. One vote up from me.